# Can I ask a duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

Can someone ask a question that has already answers (has been asked)?

One reason of asking a duplicate question is: the OP does not understand the answers provided already.

Comment: Yes, provided that the asker explains why the answers on the previous question don't fully address their question. But for relatively recent questions, I think it's better to leave a comment on the answer(s) in question.

Comment: Good. Thanks for letting me know that :)

Comment: "Can I ask a duplicate question?"  You just did.

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks :)

Comment: So very ironic, the question title!